# display chat bubble behind text

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to display a chat bubble behind some text. Essentially the questions boils down to properly scaling background images.

I am mostly an Android developer and this is easy to do with a .9 image. I want to be able to do the same for an HTML page.

What i want is create a image that i can specify which sections strech and which dont. This would allow me to best scale the image as a background.

Currently my attempt looks like this.

[image]

Here is my code for this.

```
<div style="background-image: url(../home_images/chat_right.png);background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;"><em>&ldquo;What RiteCare has done for my child is an amazing gift. Watching him grow in front of my eyes has been so incredible.&rdquo; </em>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ~Margaret</div>
```

Comment: i think you need to use a block, check this page, https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ you will need to be careful with responsive design

Comment: You can try looking into `border-image` CSS if you want nine-slicing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain old CSS. There's no reason to have to stretch and skew an image.

```
<div class="chatBubble">
<div class="message">
And then, this one time, at band camp....
</div>
</div>
<div class="triangle-down">
</div>
```

Applicable CSS:

```
.message {
  color: #000;
  font-size:14pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:left;
}

.chatBubble {
  border: 5px solid purple;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color:white;
  padding:15px;
}
.triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid purple;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  right:10%;
}
```

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fh5gg77r/

Comment: This makes sense but i specifically want to use images. The one you coded up is a simple background. I want other complex backgrounds as well.

Comment: Try this - https://jsfiddle.net/fh5gg77r/1/ - you can still use any image or pattern you want for the background of the chatbox. Any alterations to the OUTSIDE of the box can be done with CSS, just like that triangle I formed.

Comment: what i mean is that i want to be able to have for instance an image of a cloud as the chat buble instead of the purple border and triangle. In ensense i dont want to be limited with borders and triangles if posible.

Comment: A little more complicated, but you can still use CSS. https://jsfiddle.net/y16zq4cp/1/